# How to get autocomplete of CSS3 properties on Eclipse inside the <ui:style> tag of GWT UiBinder?

Tags: eclipse, css, gwt, autocomplete, uibinder

I can enable autocomplete of CSS3 properties for .css and .gss files on Eclipse by following [this answer](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=783118&goto=1388492&#msg_1388492) by Nitin DahyabhaiFriend:

> The default profile in Luna is still CSS2. Bring up the **Properties** dialog for your web project and you can change the default CSS profile for that project on the **Web Content Settings** page. If the CSS file is not in a web project, or if you don't want to use the project default, you can also set it using the file's **Properties** dialog (also **Web Content Settings** page).

... but that doesn't enable the autocompletion of CSS3 properties (such as background-position, border-radius and so on) inside `*.ui.xml` files (GWT UiBinder). For example:

```
<ui:style>
    .randomStuff {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-s <ctrl+space... no luck!>
    }
</ui:style>
```

How can I enable autocomplete of CSS3 inside those files?

Comment: The same problem occurs when using the open-source version of the [GWT Plug-in for Eclipse](https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin). I opened [the bug #79](https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues/79) to track the issue.

Comment: The xml editor has to be upgraded. I've looked into adding the feature although I haven't had time to enhance it yet. Patches are welcome. :)